# What color should i change to make powerlevel9k visible

Tags: themes, oh-my-zsh

I have following prompt

`~/repos/go/src/github.com/xyz/xyz-project > <branch_changed_icon> GG-000`

Whenever i make the code change in the directory, the last part which is `<branch_changed_icon> GG-000` goes dark black or gray. Which is is not visible on my extended monitor (monitor is shitty). If i make the commit/add, this prompt turns to green which is perfectly visible.

I was looking at `powerlevel9k.zsh-theme` file but couldn't figure out what change i have to make so that i can make this last part more visible.

Answer (score 2):

The VCS segment is a stateful one and has the state included in the variable name. 
So you have to write your Variables for the VCS segment like this: `POWERLEVEL9K_VCS_MODIFIED_BACKGROUND='red'` in your `~/.zshrc`.
Have a look at [the P9K wiki](https://github.com/bhilburn/powerlevel9k/wiki/Stylizing-Your-Prompt#special-segment-colors) for further informations.
Note that these variables will change, once the [development branch](https://github.com/bhilburn/powerlevel9k/tree/next) will be stable.

And in general, if your colors are very dark, you should consider installing a color scheme for your terminal. If you use iTerm2, you can choose [one here](https://iterm2colorschemes.com/). That affects all of your Terminal, not just single segments. A popular scheme is "Solarized Dark".

Comment: I don't want to change the theme since it wouldn't go against with rest of my setup. I was able to find the foreground color which is in `powerlevel9k.zsh-theme` file at line `1609`. Here is the line `"$1_prompt_segment" "${0}_${(U)current_state}" "$2" "${vcs_states[$current_state]}" "yellow" "$vcs_prompt" "$vcs_visual_identifier"`. I have put `yellow there temporarily. But I am unable to figure out where is the background color being set.

Comment: The magic happens inside `$1_prompt_segment`. `$1` expands to either `left` or `right`. Within this function we check for a variable that is called like the segment and state that were given to it. It is build this way to avoid people to have to change the actual code and they can set the look from outside.